# Sympy simplification of polynomial with complex coefficients

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, complex-numbers, polynomial-math

Working on a problem with polynomials with complex coefficients,
I am stuck with the following problem:

Let's say I have a polynomial `P = λ^16*z + λ^15*z^2`, where `λ` is complex.
I want to simplify having the following constraint: `λ^14 = 1`.
So, plugging in, we should get:

```
P = λ^2*z + λ*z^2.
```

I have tried `P.subs(λ**14,1)` but it doesn't work, because it assumes `λ` is real I guess. So it returns the original expression: `P = λ^16*z + λ^15*z^2`, without factoring out `λ^14`...

Comment: Did you check [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/tutorial.html#complex-numbers)?

Comment: Sympy is correct; your expected result is wrong. For example, say, `λ=e**(i * 2* pi /15)`. Then `λ**15=1`, but `λ**16` is not `1`.

Comment: @Stelios, thanks for you reply. If, as you say, we take λ=e^(i * 2* pi /15), then since λ^15=1, we should get λ^16 = λ*λ^15 = λ, right?
Thus, my expected result should be correct. Or am I missing something? Thanks again.

Comment: @Gev_2000 Yes, of course, you are right. Apologies, I misread your post.

Comment: @Stelios, no worries :) Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any simple way to achieve what you want in sympy, but you could substitute each value explicitly:

```
p = (λ**16)*z + (λ**15)*(z**2)

p = p.subs(λ**16, λ**2).subs(λ**15, λ**1)
>>> z**2*λ + z*λ**2
```

---

**Why `subs` fails to work here:**

`subs` only substitutes an expression `x**m` in `x**n` when `m` is a factor of `n`, e.g.:

```py
p.subs(λ, 1)
>>> z**2 + z
```

```py
p.subs(λ**2, 1)
>>> z**2*λ**15 + z
```

```py
p.subs(λ**3, 1)
>>> z**2 + z*λ**16
```

```py
p.subs(λ**6, 1)
>>> z**2*λ**15 + z*λ**16
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
P.simplify().subs(λ**15,1).expand()
```

Comment: Thanks, but if we have, for example, a different constraint, let's say λ^14 = 1, then we should get P = λ^2*z + λ*z^2, however your solution doesn't work in this case. No idea why...

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that λ is real, this works:

```
lambda_, z = sym.symbols('lambda z', real=True)
print((lambda_**16*z + lambda_**15*z**2).subs(lambda_**14, 1))
z**2 + z
```

Edit:
It shouldn't actually work anyway because λ may be negative. What you want is only true if λ is a positive number.

Comment: Lambda is a 14th root of unity - the only real values it could be are 1 and -1.

Comment: The result Gev_2000 asked for is only valid lambdas that are positive real numbers. They didn't specify that lambda _is_ a positive real number. If they did, they'd get the desired result. Not sure what you disagree with.

Comment: my point is you can't assume it's real - it has 12 possible non-real values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ratsimpmodprime()` function to reduce a polynomial modulo a set of other polynomials. There is also the `reduce()` function, which does something similar.

```
>>> P = λ**16*z + λ**15*z**2
>>> ratsimpmodprime(P, [λ**14 - 1])
z**2*λ + z*λ**2
```